# How to parse Json object in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, reactjs.net

I want to parse through a JSON list in reactJS. 
Here is the model that I am using

```
public class ModelEmployee
{
    public List<Employeelist> Employees { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public int Pagenumber { get; set; }
}
public class Employeelist
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public List<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

And my controller is

```
 public ActionResult Index(int pageNum = 1)
    {
        ModelEmployee model = new ModelEmployee();   
            model = new ModelEmployee();
            model.Employees = FetchAllDevices(pageNum, 10);
            model.count = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)_empService.TotalCount() / _pageSize);
            model.Pagenumber = pageNum;
            return Json(model,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            
    }
```

This is what i have tried in ReactJS code to extract each values

```
 componentWillMount: function(){  

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
    xhr.open('get', this.props.url, true);  
    xhr.onload = function () {  
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);   
        this.setState({ result: response });

    }.bind(this);  
    xhr.send();  
},  
render: function(){  
    var rows = [];  
    this.state.result.Employees.forEach(function (item) {  
        rows.push(<EmployeeRow  key={item.EmployeeID} item={item }/>);  
});
```

Its not working. But when I change the setState with this,

```
this.setState({ result: response.Employees });
```

it will work fine and can go through the Employees list. But cant access the pagenumber and count variables. Can you please help me to sort out this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you also store the count and pagenumber in the state?

```
this.setState({ 
  employees: response.Employees,
  count: response.count,
  pageNumber: response.PageNumber
});
```

Then you can access pageNumber and count from `this.state.pageNumber` and `this.state.count` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

In your onLoad callback for the XHR, you should be sure to check the readyState, to ensure the response has completed:

```
xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) { // optionally check the status
            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);   
            this.setState({ result: response });
        }
    }

}.bind(this);
```

This ensures you're reading the completed response. Try this and see if this solved the problem